# Alternative to External Table Join in Azure Database

Tags: azure, t-sql, elasticsearch, azure-sql-database

I have currently setup multiple Azure DBs on a single server primarily with different schemas.

External Queries work perfectly fine on small tables.  I am currently using an INNER JOIN on multiple tables within 2 DBs.

This works great for small tables with limited data sets since it appears to be physically copying the tables over to a temp table then performing the query.

However when I do a join on a large table ~500K rows the query will fail as the size of the table causes a timeout while it tries to copy the table to the temp directory.

Is there a way to execute the query without copying the JOIN table to a temp directory?

I have previously tried to create Stored procedures on the DB with the Large Table I am trying to join, however that DB will eventually be sunset and I will be back where I am now so I would like a longer term solution.

Comment: Parameterized operations so they are evaluated on remote databases without needing to bring the data locally https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a CROSS APPLY (Inner Join) and OUTER CROSS APPLY (Left Join) then adding the logic to a where statement within

```
Select c.Id, a.Quantity, b.Name
From Table1 a CROSS APPLY
(Select * FROM Table2 WHERE x = y) c
INNER JOIN Table3 b ON c.x = b.x
Add Join
Add Join
```

This executed the joins on the target without having to bring the whole table into a TempTable.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately consider consolidating your separate databases into one single database, eg using schemas to provide separation.  Ask yourself the question "Why are my databases split?" or is having to join across them an occasional thing?  Do you need them to be split.  If having to join across them is a regular task then consolidating them makes sense.

Alternately consider [Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance).  This is a PaaS service but gives you an experience closer to traditional SQL Server.  First off, you can have multiple databases in once instance and cross-database joins are as easy as they are in box product SQL Server.

Comment: I would normally consolidate however we are in the middle of a data migration which among other things is clearing out a load of out-dated fields and data that has built up over the years.   They still need to be "present" until we can complete the migration.

Comment: Good luck in your migration!